# sleep not working in service

Tags: suspend, ownership

I put `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60` into a unit file (service) in 18.04 Ubuntu

```
[Unit]
Description=Berkeley Open Infrastructure Network Computing Client
Documentation=man:boinc(1)
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ProtectHome=true
Type=simple
Nice=10
User=boinc
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/boinc
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60
ExecStart=/usr/bin/boinc
ExecStop=/usr/bin/boinccmd --quit
ExecReload=/usr/bin/boinccmd --read_cc_config
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f lockfile
IOSchedulingClass=idle

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also verified that sleep was at /bin

```
jstateson@rx560:/bin$ ls -l sleep
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35000 Jan 18  2018 sleep
jstateson@rx560:/bin$
```

But it didn't work.  I found the following errors in syslog

```
May 20 07:30:16 rx560 systemd[1]: boinc-client.service: Start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
May 20 07:30:16 rx560 systemd[1]: boinc-client.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
May 20 07:30:16 rx560 systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Open Infrastructure Network Computing Client.
```

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl show --property=TimeoutStartUSec [yourUnitName].service`?

Comment: Yea, see the problem.  I originally had 300 seconds and that systemctl had 1.5 minutes so 300 was too long.  When posted here I put down 60 which would have worked.  However, the 1min 30s  is too short a time as the GPU detection in BOINC fails.  I will do that infinity or whatever.  Thank you!

Comment: You may consider using a different target in the `After=` statement, like `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`. Both of those should ensure that your service is started after GPU drivers are loaded. A cleaner solution incorporating a fixed wait time before starting the service would be a systemd timer.

Comment: Tried graphical target but syslog shows error:  Job deleted to break ordering cycle starting with graphical.target/start.  Will try multiuser next

Comment: Multi-user worked fine, was unable to edit previous comment

Answer (score 0):

In your `[service]` section add this line:

```
TimeoutSec=infinity
```

For more reading: [How to change systemd service timeout value?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227017/how-to-change-systemd-service-timeout-value)

That said you are intentionally putting 60 second delay into your startup and perhaps there is a better way...

Comment: Yes, but no telling when it will be implemeneted  https://boinc.berkeley.edu/forum_thread.php?id=12946